# Persistent atop display of system stats

Tags: linux, command-line, administration

When I start [`atop`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/atop), it will blink `*** System and Process Activity since Boot ***` and show system and process activity since boot.

After 10 seconds, it will show system and process activity in the past interval (10 seconds by default).

**How can I have it continue to show system and process activity since boot?**

Simply increasing interval to a large period does not work because it won't update until that period has elapsed.

Alternatively, how can I print it for only one iteration, [like I can do with `top` (`top -bn1`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147472)?

Answer (score 0):

When starting `atop` without any flags, you can type `r` repeatedly to show the latest system activity since boot time. You must press it at least once per iteration (10 seconds by default), or it will revert back to stats in the past 10-second period.

From the help:

```
'r'  - reset counters to boot time values
```